# Pytorch nn.CrossEntropyLoss stays near 5 without convergence

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, classification, loss

I have build a simpel DL net with the Pytorch ResNet API to train the Stanford Cars Dataset. My task is image classification. I use the CrossEntropyLoss as my loss function.

```
transform = T.Compose([
    T.Resize(224), 
    T.CenterCrop(224), 
    T.ToTensor(), 
    T.Normalize(mean=[.5, .5, .5], std=[.5, .5, .5])
])

class data_dataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, img_path, train_labelspath, img_transform=None):
        with open(train_labelspath, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            self.img_list = [os.path.join(img_path, i.split()[1]) for i in lines]
            self.labels_list = [i.split()[2] for i in lines]
            self.img_transform = img_transform
        f.close()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img = self.img_list[index]
        label = self.labels_list[index]
        img = Image.open(img).convert('RGB').resize((224, 224))
        if self.img_transform is not None:
            img = self.img_transform(img)
        return img, label

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels_list)

train_data = data_dataset(data_path, train_labelpath, img_transform=transform)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

net = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
net.fc = nn.Linear(2048, 196)
#net.add_module = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
epoch = 1000
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(net.parameters)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

for ep in range(epoch):
    for i, (img, label) in enumerate(train_loader):
        net.train()
        label = np.array(label, int)
        label = torch.LongTensor(label)
        img = torch.FloatTensor(img)
        label.to(device)
        img.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(img)

        loss = criterion(outputs, label - 1)
        loss.backward()
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("epoch:{}, batch:{}, loss is:{}".format(ep, i, loss))

        optimizer.step()
```

However the Loss function has not changed：

```
epoch:0, batch:0, loss is:5.312277793884277
epoch:0, batch:10, loss is:5.654966354370117
epoch:0, batch:20, loss is:5.4962687492370605
epoch:0, batch:30, loss is:5.62110710144043
...
epoch:0, batch:590, loss is:5.2842936515808105
epoch:0, batch:600, loss is:5.304643630981445
epoch:0, batch:610, loss is:5.143134117126465
epoch:0, batch:620, loss is:5.408026218414307
```

Why? This problem has troubled me for four days. I don't konw what should I do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, did you try to put `net.train()` outside the loop?

Comment: @WbytheSea，Thank you, I just try to do it, it still don't change.

Comment: Have you trained it for several epochs? The loss values you posted are within the first epoch, at this point it hasn't even seen all the possible images and since you have 196 classes it takes a while to learn them. At the beginning, the model will almost always be wrong. Compare the loss per epoch, not per batch. And if you can, increase the batch size, as ResNet uses BatchNorm, which doesn't work all that well for smaller batch sizes, alternatively you could freeze the BatchNorm layers.

Comment: @Michael Jungo Thanks for your suggestion， I train it with my own PC, so I guess the net need a long time trainning. ：）